# Check Registry Key for Installed Software & Token, Delim Explanation

Tags: batch-file, scripting, token, delimiter, registrykey

I have been reading on this site and found good information but I am still a little confused on how the the script below is working? I have been checking scripts for the portions I need but I am very new to this and am still unsure of how to do this. I believe "Tokens" are the admin rights to retrieve the information you need and "Delims" are what separates the list of computer names in a list you have (text file)?

I need to go through a text file I have, I used dsquery to retrieve computer names in certain OU's in AD and have put them in a text file.I want to ping the PC to make sure it's on then check for a specific Registry Key to confirm how many installations were completed and how many are not.
This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

if %USERNAME% NEQ XXXXX (
echo.
echo   THE ACCOUNT YOU ARE USING IS NOT AUTHORIZED TO RUN THIS SCRIPT.
echo.
echo        Logoff and back on with the correct account.
echo.
pause
goto:eof
)
set _date=14Aug2015
set _version=Shockwave12.1.9.150

:infile
REM Specify PC Query List
REM Query list must be a text file (filename.txt)
REM Query filename can be set manually:
cls
echo.
echo Account running this script must have administrator priviledges on remote machines.
echo.
echo Enter the filename only not the extension. (i.e querylist)  
echo.
set inputfile=
set /p inputfile=Enter the Query list file name:

if not exist %inputfile%.txt goto :infile
echo.
echo.

title "Shockwave 12.1.9.150" %inputfile%

:dlbchk
REM Double check
cls
echo.
echo Last chance to re-enter list and time...
echo.
echo You have chosen to check the registry on the machines on this Query list '%inputfile%.txt'
echo.
set inputchk=
set /p inputchk=To continue press 'Y' and To Quit press 'Q' :

if "%inputchk%" == "Y" goto :output
if "%inputchk%" == "y" goto :output
if "%inputchk%" == "Q" goto:eof
if "%inputchk%" == "q" goto:eof
goto :infile

:output
REM Check for Adobe Shockwave Player 12.1.9.159 - {699025AA-475E-45F2-9C9B-9A489CAD2C10}
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (%inputfile%.txt) do call :pingtest %%i
echo. >> %logfile%
goto:eof
REG QUERY "\\%1\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{699025AA-475E-45F2-9C9B-9A489CAD2C10}
IF %errorlevel%=="0" Echo %1 >> \\Server\Share\Shockwave\Shockwave 12.1.9.159\Installed.txt
IF %errorlevel%=="1" Echo %1 >> \\Server\Share\Shockwave\Shockwave 12.1.9.159\NotInstalled.txt

:pingtest
REM Check if device is available
echo. >> %logfile%
ping -w 500 -n 1 %1>nul  
if errorlevel 1 (
echo %1,offline >> %logfile%
goto:eof
)
```

Comment: Have you studied [the documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) or the help displayed when running `for /?` from the command prompt? Should take no more than a few minutes, it contains all the info about tokens and delims.

Comment: I have done that for everything else and completely forgot to look there for answers, what I was finding seemed to be different answers to the same questions. I will do that now, thanks so much.